# Remove outliers in a row-wise manner for multiple groups

Tags: r

My matrix`deg` has column names that match the row names of `clin.info`, which has a column `subtype`. I want to remove the outliers from `deg` for each `subtype` group using interquartile range.

My code did not return any rows.

Code:

```
for (rows in 1:nrow(deg)){
  Q <- quantile(rows, probs=c(.25, .75), na.rm = FALSE)
  iqr <- IQR(rows)
  up <-  Q[2]+1.5*iqr # Upper Range  
  low<- Q[1]-1.5*iqr # Lower Range
  eliminated<- subset(deg, rows > (Q[1] - 1.5*iqr) & rows < (Q[2]+1.5*iqr))
}
```

Input

```
> dput(clin.info[,c("survival", "subtype")][1:5,])
structure(list(survival = c("lts", "lts", "lts", "lts", "lts"
), subtype = c("2a", "1a", "2a", "1a", "1a")), row.names = c("TCGA.Y8.A8S1.01", 
"TCGA.Y8.A8S0.01", "TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01", "TCGA.Y8.A8RY.01", "TCGA.Y8.A897.01"
), class = "data.frame")

> dput(deg[1:5,1:5])
structure(c(493, 2498, 387, 1154.93, 362, 43800000, 152900000000, 60300000000, 194400000.56, 
5940000, 1270, 3300, 735, 2120.99, 971, 201, 1921, 227, 1246.66, 
411, 717, 2655, 624, 2049.36, 551), dim = c(5L, 5L), dimnames = list(
    c("ADAMTS13", "MST1", "TUBE1", "RPAIN", "NPHP1"), c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01", 
    "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01", 
    "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01")))
```

Expected output:

```
structure(c(493, 10000, 387, 1154.93, 1270, 3300, 735, 2120.99, 971, 201, 1921, 227, 1246.66, 
411, 717, 2655, 624, 2049.36, 551), dim = c(5L, 5L), dimnames = list(
    c("ADAMTS13", "MST1", "TUBE1", "RPAIN", "NPHP1"), c("TCGA.Y8.A8S1.01", 
    "TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01", "TCGA.Y8.A8RY.01", 
    "TCGA.Y8.A897.01")))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work *

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

deg |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = 'colname_deg') |>
  left_join(clin.info |> rownames_to_column('colname_deg'),
            by = 'colname_deg'
            ) |>
  group_by(subtype) |>
  mutate(low = quantile(value, 1/4), high = quantile(value, 3/4)) |>
  rowwise() |>
  filter(between(value, low, high))
```

* not checked, as your example output structure throws an error, and none of the colnames of `deg` is among `clin.info`'s rownames.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a matrix, and want matrix back, `apply` is your friend with `MARGIN=1` for rows. Use a function like `rm_outlier` instead of a loop.

```
rm_outlier <- \(x) {
  Q <- quantile(x, probs=c(.25, .75), na.rm=FALSE)
  iqr <- IQR(x)
  up <-  Q[2] + 1.5*iqr # Upper Range  
  low <- Q[1] - 1.5*iqr # Lower Range
  x[x <= (Q[1] - 1.5*iqr) | x >= (Q[2] + 1.5*iqr)] <- NA_real_
  x
}

t(apply(X=deg, MARGIN=1, FUN=rm_outlier))
#          TCGA.2K.A9WE.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01
# ADAMTS13          493.00              NA         1270.00          201.00          717.00
# MST1             2498.00              NA         3300.00         1921.00         2655.00
# TUBE1             387.00              NA          735.00          227.00          624.00
# RPAIN            1154.93              NA         2120.99         1246.66         2049.36
# NPHP1             362.00              NA          971.00          411.00          551.00
```

The result comes transposed, so we have to transpose back using `t()`.

---

*Data:*

```
deg <- structure(c(493, 2498, 387, 1154.93, 362, 43800000, 1.529e+11, 
6.03e+10, 194400000.56, 5940000, 1270, 3300, 735, 2120.99, 971, 
201, 1921, 227, 1246.66, 411, 717, 2655, 624, 2049.36, 551), dim = c(5L, 
5L), dimnames = list(c("ADAMTS13", "MST1", "TUBE1", "RPAIN", 
"NPHP1"), c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01")))
```